# How to stop (deallocate) SQL server in Azure?

Tags: sql-server, database, azure

I have an SQL database created, and also a virtual Server. Both in Azure.

How can I stop the server, so that usage costs are not being calculated when I do not make use of the database (database server)? I am looking for a similar feature currently available for VM's (stop and deallocating a VM so usage costs are not longer being calculated).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i believe there is not way to do that now. You can vote for the feature on the [official voting site](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/6931152-please-add-ability-to-temporarily-turn-off-on-sql) and ask in the Q&A section or ask product planner Program Manager Guy Haycock (he answered the question on the voting site) directly.

Comment: I have asked for feedback on the official voting site but still no response from anybody :( :(

Comment: @MGroen please ask Guy directly as he put his contacts in the answer